# TypeError: argument 1 must be pygame.Surface, not list & more

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to get my code to run, without the scaling transformation bit, it runs but as soon as I press space it crashes the game, targeting `win.blit(char, (x,y))`. With the scaling part, it doesn't run at all an targets `pg.transform.scale(walkRight, (64,64))`. Please help me thank you! Also can you explain me why for some reasons my Idle pictures/sprites are facing backwards and I copied some of the sprites which could only face on the right and flipped them on editing however it doesn't do the movement animation at all compared to the right side which does it perfectly?

My code is:

```
import pygame as pg #making pygame module easier to use throughout the entire program
pg.init() #initialising pygame

win= pg.display.set_mode((1200,600))
pg.display.set_caption("Path of the Shinobi")
win.fill((0,0,0))
#Sprites loading
walkRight = [pg.image.load('pics/RR.png'), pg.image.load('pics/RR2.png'), pg.image.load('pics/RR3.png'), pg.image.load('pics/RR4.png'), pg.image.load('pics/RR5.png'), pg.image.load('pics/RR6.png'), pg.image.load('pics/RR7.png'), pg.image.load('pics/RR8.png'), pg.image.load('pics/RR9.png'), pg.image.load('pics/RR10.png')]
walkLeft = [pg.image.load('pics/LR.png'), pg.image.load('pics/LR2.png'), pg.image.load('pics/LR3.png'), pg.image.load('pics/LR4.png'), pg.image.load('pics/LR5.png'), pg.image.load('pics/LR6.png'), pg.image.load('pics/LR7.png'), pg.image.load('pics/LR8.png'), pg.image.load('pics/LR9.png'), pg.image.load('pics/LR10.png')]
bg = pg.image.load('bg.jpg')
char = [pg.image.load('pics/Idle.png'), pg.image.load('pics/Idle2.png'), pg.image.load('pics/Idle3.png'), pg.image.load('pics/Idle4.png'), pg.image.load('pics/Idle5.png'), pg.image.load('pics/Idle6.png'), pg.image.load('pics/Idle7.png'), pg.image.load('pics/Idle8.png'), pg.image.load('pics/Idle9.png'), pg.image.load('pics/Idle10.png')]

walkRight = pg.transform.scale(walkRight,(64,64))
walkLeft = pg.transform.scale(walkLeft,(64,64))
char = pg.transform.scale(char,(64,64))
bg = pg.transform.scale(bg,(1200,600))

clock = pg.time.Clock()

#default position of the character in x and y axis format
x= 50 
y= 425
width= 64 # width of character
height = 64 #height of character
vel= 5 #speed of character
#jumping system
isJump = False
jumpCount = 10
left = False
right = False
walkCount = 0


def redrawGameWindow():
    global walkCount
    win.blit(bg, (0,0)) #so the character doesn't draw itself again 

# putting character on the window surface
    if walkCount + 1 >= 27:
        walkCount = 0

    if left:
        win.blit(walkLeft[walkCount//3], (x,y))
        walkCount += 1
    elif right:
        win.blit(walkRight[walkCount//3], (x,y))
        walkCount += 1
    else:
        win.blit(char, (x,y))


    pg.display.update() #to make the things appear

#Main Loop
run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(27)

#check for events
    for event in pg.event.get():
        if event.type == pg.QUIT:
            run = False

    keys = pg.key.get_pressed()
#setting up a list for the keys    
#this section is to check if the following keys have been pressed or held on
#allow the character to move upon pressing certain keys
#prevent the character from going off the screen
#Jumping allows user to move left and right
    if keys[pg.K_LEFT]and x > vel: 
        x -= vel
        left = True
        right = False


    if keys[pg.K_RIGHT] and x < 500 - width - vel:
        x += vel
        right = True
        left = False

    else:
        right = False
        left = True
        walkCount= 0

#jumping system
    if not(isJump):

        if keys[pg.K_SPACE]:
            isJump = True
            right = False
            left = False
            walkCount = 0

#if jumping allow the character to be brought up and down (gravity)
#move character by a number of pixels     
    else:
        if jumpCount >= -10:
            neg = 1
            if jumpCount < 0:
                neg = -1
            y -= (jumpCount ** 2) * 0.5 * neg
            jumpCount -= 1

        else:
            isJump = False
            jumpCount = 10

    redrawGameWindow()

pg.quit()
```

Comment: Thank you @Rabbid76 , as soon as I have time I will deal with it and notify you :) I am just really busy with Biology right now and it's so stressful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `walkRight`, `walkLeft` and `char` are list of surfaces, you've to scale each element of the list:

```py
walkRight = [pg.transform.scale(img,(64,64)) for img in walkRight]
walkLeft = [pg.transform.scale(img,(64,64)) for img in walkLeft]
char = [pg.transform.scale(img,(64,64)) for img in char]
```

But note, the entire code which loads and scales the images can be simplified a lot. Further more, I recommend to use [`pygame.transform.smoothscale()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/transform.html#pygame.transform.smoothscale) rather than [`pygame.transform.scale()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/transform.html#pygame.transform.scale):

```py
imgRight = ['pics/RR.png'] + ['pics/RR' + str(i) + '.png' for i in range(2, 11)]
imgLeft  = ['pics/LR.png'] + ['pics/LR' + str(i) + '.png' for i in range(2, 11)]
imgChar  = ['pics/Idle.png'] + ['pics/Idle' + str(i) + '.png' for i in range(2, 11)]

walkRight = [pg.transform.smoothscale(pg.image.load(img), (64,64)) for img in imgRight]
walkLeft  = [pg.transform.smoothscale(pg.image.load(img), (64,64)) for img in imgLeft]
char      = [pg.transform.smoothscale(pg.image.load(img), (64,64)) for img in imgChar]

bg = pg.transform.smoothscale(pg.image.load('bg.jpg'), (1200,600))
```

---

`char` is a list of [`pygame.Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) objects, but the argument to [`.blit`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.blit) has to be a single Surface object, rather than a list of surfaces. e.g.:

<s>`win.blit(char, (x,y))`</s>

```py
win.blit(char[walkCount//3], (x,y))
```

Comment: Amazing, thank you so much! Now one issue is that for the sprites they were originally right sided, I edited them on photos so they can be flipped but it doesn't load all the images only one of them and the character be sliding across with no animation whatsoever (left pre-running position slide - 1st left sprite). I would also like to know how to implement the jumping sprites into my code. Could you please explain me how to solve this, thank you :)